# Laravel Query behave differently on IPv4 Vs. IPv6 Environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ip, laravel-5.1

I have a weird situation here that I never seen before while using Laravel. 
I have the same code base on different set up, 1 in IPv4 VM, 1 in IPv6 VM.

This is the data in the database.

[image]

This is how I normally query it.

```
// $ap = '102030405067';
$gw = Gateway::where('cpe_mac','=',$ap)->first();
dd($gw);
```

In my IPv4 Set up, I got :

```
{#541 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"account_id": "50"
  +"cpe_mac": "102030405067"
  +"gw_id": "1956692524588882"
  +"gw_secret": "zUIyaQfCntob2thL6uR4uQfBvmlCei-5q_oVSJnyeSc"
  +"fb_wifi_enable": "1"
  +"created_at": "2017-10-10 14:41:17"
  +"updated_at": "2017-10-10 14:41:17"
}
```

In my IPv6 Set up, I got :

`null`

---

## Try #2

`dd(Gateway::all());`.

## Result

In IPv4, I got all the records returned.

[image]

In IPv6, I got this empty collection

`Collection {#542 \u25bc
  #items: []
}`

[image]

---

The most confusing part is, other tables seems to work fine, this `gateways` seems to be the only one that causing the problem.

I triple checked my Gateway model name, and table name. They spelled correclty.

---

- Have you guys seen something like this before ?
- How would one go about and debug this issue further ?
- What else should I try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest - I don't think it's possible.

Make sure that in both cases `$ap` contains exact same value.  You can use `trim($ap)` just in case to be double-sure it doesn't contain extra special characters.

Also make sure on both VMs you have same data in database. Now it seems in one VM you have data in database and in second you don't.

**EDIT**

It's not possible there is direct problem in Laravel, so:

- make sure in both VMs you have data in your databases - on both VMs run `SELECT * FROM gateways` to verify on both you have any records (you haven't mentioned that both VMs are using same database so I assume they are different)
- make sure in both VMs you have valid database set in your `.env` file
- on both VMS run `php artisan config:clear` just to make sure you don't have cached invalid database connection

Comment: Let me try this `trim($ap)`

Comment: I've tried `dd(Gateway::all());`. In IPv4, I got all the records return. In IPv6, I got this empty collection `Collection {#542 \u25bc
  #items: []
}`

Comment: So are you sure that on both servers you have data in `gateways` table? If you don't this is obvious any record won't be find. Make sure on both servers you have values in this table

Comment: Yes. I am sure. Both VMs was pointing to the same databases for testing.

Comment: So when you connect to one database and run `SELECT * FROM gateways where cpe_mac = '102030405067'` you are getting one record, and on second for exact same query you are getting the same record? What does `cpe_mac` contains - is it not MAC address or something similar and it differs for both VMs?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM gateways where cpe_mac = '102030405067'` does return something.

Comment: Is it returning same on both databases? Are you sure in `.env` you have valid databases set? Are you sure `$ap` has exact same value on both servers?

Comment: I will double check those against your updated answer 

Comment: Your hint does help a lot. My mistake. I connected to the wrong database IP because they look very similar. Your answer are corrent.

Answer (score -1):

**What is an IP address ? What are IPv6, IPv4 protocols, what is difference between them?**

***What is an IP address?***

IP (internet protocol) is the protocol by which is sent data from one computer to another device on the internet. Each computer on the internet has different IP address identify it from all other computers on the internet. An IP address is a numeric address and identifier for a computer or device on a network. Every device has and has an IP address for communication purposes.

***Internet protocol version 4 (IPv4)***

Internet protocol version 4 (IPv4) is the fourth version of the internet protocol (IP). This protocol most used today in data communications over different kinds of the network because it supports all devices.IPv4 invented in 1970.

***Internet protocol version 6 (IPv6)***

Internet protocol version 6 (IPv6) It is the most recent update version protocol of the internet. That provides an identification and location system for computers and routes traffic across the internet. IPv6 invented in 1998.

***DIFFERENCE BETWEEN IPv4 VS IPv6***

IPv4

1.IPv4 is a 32-bit address.
2.IPv4 is the numbering address method.

IPv6

1.IPv6 IS 128-bit address.
2.IPv6 is the alphanumeric address method.

For more information [click](https://apperweb.com/what-is-an-ip-address/) here